# Ubuntu14.04 Not detecting AMD GPU instead showing Intel Integrated GPU

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

On:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)

I'm getting above.

I also have AMD Radeon R5 m330 GPU on my laptop and want to use it as my GPU.
How to do that?

Comment: Is it enabled in BIOS? Is this 14.04.5?

Comment: It is most likely disabled in BIOS/UEFI. It would be listed otherwise regardless of what drivers are in use..

Comment: You will see it is you run `lspci` or `lspci  | grep Display`

Comment: @Pilot6  I want to use AMD GPU as my default GPU or say main GPU. How to do that???